# How to reuse object constructor?

Tags: javascript

This is how I create objects from a hash of properties:

```
var object = new function (data) {
  var self = this;
  self.property = data.property;
  self.anotherProperty = data.anotherProperty;

  self.method = function () { return 'something'; }
  self.update = function (newData) {
     //what is here ? 
     //i could have written:
     self.property = newData.property;
     self.anotherProperty = newData.anotherProperty;
     //but why not reuse the constructor?
   }
};
```

I wonder how to reuse this function (constructor) to update an object from hash.
So that:

```
object.update(newData)
```

would update current object properties from `newData` hash the same way it is done in the constructor function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By giving the constructor a name?

```
function MyNotReallyClass(data){
  var self = this;
  self.property = data.property;
  self.method = function () { return 'something'; }
  self.update = MyMyNotReallyClass;
};
```

you can can now call

```
var obj = new MyNotReallyClass(data);
var obj2 = new MyNotReallyClass(data);
```

and

```
obj.update(data);
```

i hope this helps.. i not 100% sure, because i'm learning too.. but yeah try it ;)

**edit**: after reading this comment of you: "But that would return a new instance, wouldn't it? Which i don't want."

i think you can write the Update function and call it in your constructor

```
var object = new function (data) {
  var self = this;
  self.update = function (newData) {  
   self.property = data.property;
   self.method = function () { return 'something'; }
   // and other things You want to do in constructor and update
  }
  self.update(data);
}
```

;

Comment: Hey, good thinking! You turned the problem upside down, cool.. This allows the function to stay anonymous.